# Angular / Firestore - Await document update, add, or set

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

Is it possible to await a successful document write to Firestore?

I have a component that calls an add function in a service:

```
save(){
  this.aService.new();
}
```

In the service I have a standard angular fire add function:

```
new(){
  this.afs.collection<any>(`col/doc/col`).add({
     title: "A new Title",
  });
}
```

I would like to react to a successful `add`, `update` or action in my component so that once the write to the DB is successful, my component can display a message, or close / hide an element. I've tried adding an `async / await` to the component save function, but I'm not overly clued up on promises to know how best to integrate it correctly.

Comment: I haven't used Firestore myself, but you could try to listen to changes using the `this.afs.collection<any>(`col/doc/col`).valueChanges()` function. Related doc: https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#valuechanges-idfield-string-

Comment: In my opinion you should learn JavaScript first then TypeScript then frameworks like Angular. Or may be not Angular becouse this framework is really hard. Vue or React.

Answer (score 1):

The add() function should return a promise.
So you should be able to handle the promise as follows:

```
    this.afs.collection<any>(`col/doc/col`).add({
     title: "A new Title",
    }).then(result => {
    // handle success
    }).catch(err => {
     // handle error
   });
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart#web-version-8_2

If you want to return a promise from the service your function could look like this:

```
addToDb(): Promise<any> {
 return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
   this.afs.collection<any>(`col/doc/col`).add({
     title: "A new Title",
   }).then(result => {
     resolve(result);
   }).catch(err => {
     reject(err);
   });
```

})
}

Comment: Thanks @Raffael! - This is the usual approach I would take if I wanted to perform an action within the service. In my post, the call is coming from the component, and I would like to change things in the component upon the completion of the action. In the above example, it would mean doing everything in the service correct? Is there anything I could add to the component call that would detect when the service function is complete?

Comment: @Que: Return the Promise from the service and provide callbacks in the component.

Comment: Thanks for the update Raffael and the response Michael. Much appreciated. That's great and I believe works well. However, is it possible to detect the success or failure from the component call?

Comment: Yes, by handling the promise in the component.  e.g. this.afs.addToDb().then(res => {}).catch(err =>{})

Comment: The promise is my normal, but I'm having a problem w/it.  In service I have: